# How to do this effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this text effect in illustrator? That stroke type?

Comment: The wanted shape considered as 3D is not extruded planar text. The text seems like it's extruded radially, ie. the surface is cylindral. Illustrator hasn't that extrude mode, but pure 2D work isn't difficult in this case. At first write the text with black stroke and white fill. Then warp the text to the wanted form using envelope distort. Draw with pen the thickness as a new black shape.

Answer (score 2):

Right now I am seeing a combination of three different elements.

1. I would create text similar to the one you see here. For my example, I am just using some bold text.

[image]

2. The type has been warped to form an arc <kbd>Effect</kbd> > <kbd>Warp</kbd> > <kbd>Arc</kbd> . So now you could take text and apply this text.

[image]

3. Now you need to Extrude your text so <kbd>Effect</kbd> > <kbd>3D</kbd> > <kbd>Extrude & Bevel</kbd> . This step you need to play with the settings in order to rotate your 3D text the correct way.

[image]

4.Now what I found is that when you expand the appearance of your text <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Expand Appearance</kbd>, you can then play with the colors of the objects, and also you can add the stroke to the white portion of your text.

[image]

So if you were to play around with those three effects on a piece of text, I think that you could achieve a similar result.

[image]

Comment: Ah yeah you are right for some reason at first it looked like a dropshadow to me.

Comment: Warp > Arch instead of Arc will keep the sides vertical, more like the example